# What is more efficient - Approximation of 2nd order derivative or Sherman–Morrison formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a multi-dimensional function $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and its gradient with partial derivatives:
$$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial d}{\partial x_1}\\
\frac{\partial d}{\partial x_2}\\
...\\
\frac{\partial d}{\partial x_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Assume, a step-by-step algorithm needs $\nabla f$ and the $\textit{Hessean}$ matrix $H_f$ in each step for approximating an optimization problem, what would be more efficient (computation wise) for approximating the $\textit{Hessian}$ matrix:

1. Using Sherman-Morrison formula in each step (which is done in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula
2. Using methods like $f_{x_1}^{''} = \frac{\nabla f(x_1 + h, x_2, ..., x_n) - \nabla f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)}{h}$ for each matrix element - I don't know how much operations this method needs in terms of $\mathcal{O}$

Comment: Did you check the [BFGS method](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=BFGS_method)? These quasi-Newton methods do exactly that, apply low-rank updates to the Hessean (named after a person, not the region in Germany like the fabric/wallpaper) resp. its inverse, and are well explored.

Comment: @LutzL That's exactly the method I am referring to. But why is it cheapter to do these updates instead of calculating the numerical derivatives? Or is it cheaper at all?

Comment: You compare a couple of matrix-vector products and vector-vector linear operations with a total of $O(n^2)$ operations, to $n+1$ evaluations of the gradient or $n^2$ evaluations of the function, plus the $O(n^3)$ inversion of the matrix. Depending on how expensive the function evaluation is, there might indeed be cases where the method 2) is cheaper, but they will be rare in serious applications.

Comment: @LutzL  I think the $\textit{Hessean}$ matrix is symmetrical so the linear system could be solved by the $\textit{CG}$ algorithm in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ for example

Comment: @LutzL  I updated my comment - sorry. If calculating the numerical derivatives of the hessean matrix is $O(n^2)$ and solving the linear system is also $O(n^2)$ due to the $\textit{CG}$ algorithm - we are still in $O(n^2)$. I don't really see the advantage of the rank-1 updates :(

Comment: CG converges in $\ll n$ steps only if the eigenvalues are extremely clustered. And even then it depends on the target accuracy what resolution you apply to the clustering.

Comment: Imagine that the evaluation of $f$ has a cost of $O(n^2)$ or higher. (It is more than $O(n)$ if all input variables are used in the function.) In that case $n^2$ evaluations result in an effort of $O(n^4)$ or higher.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you very much! This really helped me alot